# ngshow/hide angular using ng-click

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to create a small animation when button is clicked it will show a div and hide when its clicked again. searchPanel is opacity 0 in the css was hoping a toggle effect rather than showing/hiding.

```
<button class="searchCtrl" ng-click="clickthis">Toggle</button>
    <div class="searchPanel" ng-show="showthis">
        <form action="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter postcodde" class="form-control input-sm mb-10">
                <select name="jobtype" id="" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option value="permanent">Permanent</option>
                    <option value="parttime">Part-time</option>
                    <option value="contract">Contract</option>
                </select>
        </form>
    </div>

.searchPanel{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    //opacity: 1;
}
button{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I am using bootstraps collapse for this effect, https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse

Comment: What is `clickthis`? You should call a function. Try `ng-click="clickthis()"` maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 <button class="searchCtrl" ng-click="showthis=!showthis">Toggle</button>
```

to show/hide the animation.
 here is a pluncker: [pluncker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KwkF0Iow8PyWtBAUBZ0B?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to put a delay so it won't just pop? I meant similar to transition effect

Comment: Yes like Denis said you can use ngAnimate: here is a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/2kflbqJntYyHdheILisD?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/8Yz7S/57/) there's a jsFiddle with your working example.
You just have to change your buttong to

```
<button class="searchCtrl" ng-click="showThis=!showThis">Toggle</button>
```

try reading the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) for ngClick.